# Video URL from my server is not playing video inside <video> tag in browser. but web URL for the video plays perfectly

Tags: java, html, web-services, mime-types, wildfly-9

I have two option to upload a video.
1) Provide web url for the video. or
2) Upload the video.

`<video>` tag with src as web url works fine but uploaded video will not be played when server path is given in src attribute of  tag.

Here are my urls.
1) Web url : https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 (Play the video).
2) Server URL : http://192.168.2.161:8180\files\Advertisement_Documents\03-29-2018\16\1522303134282\1522303134282.mp4 (Doesn't play)

Answer (score 0):

try to download the first video and put it on your server, does it work?

Comment: could you please post your browser console output

Answer (score 0):

Your Server-URL is a link in a local network and it is only working when you call your website within the network.

I assume your Website isn't lying under 192.168.x.xxx. So you got a FTP Server where your Data is lying? Save the video there and call it with your Domain. UNder Wordpress you could do this with some php, which returns the path to the theme as example.

But you got the option to link it with the webaddress, what's the problem about it? Do it with the webaddress.

If you want to setting up your own server at home try this [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Set-up-your-very-own-Web-server/).

Answer (score 0):

At your server, use the [301 HTTP Status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301), so clients will understand the response as an URL to be redirected instead of a simple plain text.